# How to have a delayed sync of 2 min between 2 mysql database on same local machine

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql database test1 and test2 on same machine.
In test1 there is a table named employee and is updating regularly, i need to update a table employee  on database test2 having same table name with 2 min time delay just like replication between 2 tables with 2 min  time delay.

This mysql server is installed on linux operating system, Please help me out.

Comment: consider mysql [Create Event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) functionality. Every task is different, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935)  was an example of one I wrote up. Yours could run every minute or two, picking up rows where updt_dt (datetime) is in a date_diff range of 120 seconds, and has not been dragged over to the other db. Once replicated to db2, the table in db1 could have a `replicated` column set to 1 or the like.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, Can you please elaborate by an example. It will be help me a lot.

Comment: I elaborated in the example link above