# mysql : How to update or insert new rows DAILY?

Tags: mysql, triggers

My project have to show `3 rows` to user and that'll see `new 3 random rows` in next morning

this is my table.. how can i replace or insert new rows automatically everyday

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| userID | userNAME  |     chaID       |     chaNAME     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      1 | Jane      |          4      | Watering        |
|      2 | Cristian  |          3      | Early Sleeping  |
|      3 | Jumbo     |          12     | Playing sport   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I really have no idea to deal with it .. should i make a trigger?

Thank you so much

Comment: Only 3 rows will be available rite?
If yes, why do you want to insert new rows daily. U can randomly select the rows.

Comment: @DijoDavid thank you >_< , Actually this table was selected from the other table by random and the chaID should have 3 for each user .. so how to randomly select the rows  ?

Comment: I assume user and cha table is 2 different tables and the one you have mentioned is relation table. correct? Application is built in which language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Comment: @DijoDavid yes this is a relation table from user table and challenge table ,I built with PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the mysql [Create event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) functionality. See my answer to [One Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935). Create a daily event, and work whatever magic you want inside the BEGIN / END block. Such as deleting, and inserting.

As for selecting random rows, look into the likes of

```
select col1, col2 
from otherTable
order by rand()
limit 3;  -- just 3 rows
```

To insert into one table from another (with **random**), just combine insert and select into one statement, such as

```
insert into myTable (col1,col2)
select col1, col2 
from otherTable
order by rand()
limit 3;
```

`myTable` undoubtedly needs to have userId's or the like. That can be performed by doing a `cross join` on a user table to put 3 new rows in a day for each user.

```
insert into myTable (userId,col1,col2)
select u.userId,o.col1, o.col2 
from userTable u
cross join otherTable o
order by rand()
limit 3;
```

So there, just to leave you with something. I know you are new. Welcome to the stack.

Comment: Thank you so much ,Drew 
I'm a newbie and the event function is very useful. if it's going well I'll tell you after ... >_<